# How prove this mathematical analysis by zorich from page 233

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $f$ be twice differentiable on an interval $I$,Let

> $$M_{0}=\sup_{x\in I}{|f(x)|},M_{1}=\sup_{x\in I}{|f'(x)|},M_{2}=\sup_{x\in I}{|f''(x)|}$$

show that

> (a):$$M_{1}\le 2\sqrt{M_{0}M_{2}}$$
>   if the length of $I$ is not less than $2\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$

(b):the numbers $2$ and $\sqrt{2}$ (in part a) cannot be replaced by smaller numbers.

> My try:for part $(a)$ I can prove if the length of $I$ is not less than $4\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$

my proof:

> $$f(c)-f(x)=f'(x)(c-x)+\dfrac{f''(x+\theta_{1}(c-x))}{2}(c-x)^2$$
>   let $c-x=h$
>   then we have
>   $$f'(x)=\dfrac{f(c)-f(x)}{h}-\dfrac{f''(x+\theta_{1}h)}{2}h$$
>   Thus
>   $$f'(x)\le\dfrac{2M_{0}}{h}+\dfrac{1}{2}M_{2}h$$
>   Now taking $h=2\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$, which in turn implies that
>   $$M_{1}\le2\sqrt{M_{0}M_{2}}$$
>   and $$c=x+h=2\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}+x>2\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$$
>   so  the length of $I$ is $2c$ and  not less than $4\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$

so Now  How part(a)?

and for part(b) How prove it? and How take example for the best numbers$\sqrt{2}$?

**By the way**

This problem is from **Mathematical Analysis I(Zorich )Page 233 problem 9.**

Thank you evryone

Comment: This problem statement is missing crucial information compared to the book (which can be previewed on Google Books). For example, $I$ is assumed to be a *closed* interval or $\mathbb R$ in the book. Which version of the exercise do you want solved? Please fix the problem statement here.

Comment: Hi, china math. As commented by  Ayman Hourieh, the statement of your question is different from the original question in the book. For your question, given part (a), as shown in my answer below, the correct statement of part (b) should be "the number 2 in part (a) cannot be replaced by a smaller number". Could you please edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @AymanHourieh, let me ask you question, please? Here $I$ is supposed to be any interval or just closed interval? I inclined to think that $I$ should be closed interval because if $I$ is the open interval whose length is exactly $2\sqrt{M_0/M_2}$ then the result is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a) We should assume that $M_2>0$. Denote the length of $I$ by $|I|$ and denote 
$$l=2\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}.$$ 
If $|I|\ge l$, then for any $x\in I$, there exist $h,k\ge 0$, such that $x+h,x-k\in I$ and $h+k=l$. As shown in your argument, using Taylor's expansion, we have:
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h^2\tag{1}$$
and
$$f(x-k)=f(x)-f'(x)k+\frac{f''(\zeta)}{2}k^2\tag{2},$$
where $x\le\xi\le x+h$ and $x-k\le\zeta\le x$.
Noting that $h^2+k^2\le l^2$, $(1)-(2)$ yields
$$|f'(x)|\cdot l\le |f(x+h)|+|f(x-k)|+\frac{1}{2}\left(|f''(\xi)|h^2+|f''(\zeta)|k^2\right)\le 2M_0+\frac{M_2}{2}l^2,$$
and the conclusion follows.

---

(b) The best constant in (a) should be $2$. That is to say,

(i) there exists $f:I\to\Bbb R$, such that $|I|=l=2\sqrt{\frac{M_0}{M_2}}$ and $M_1=2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$;

(ii) for every $0<\lambda<1$, there exists $f:I\to\Bbb R$, such that $I\ge \lambda l$ and $M_1>2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$.

**Example:** For any $a\in [0,1)$, let 
$$f(x)=2x^2-1-a^2,\quad I=[a,1].$$ Then $|I|=1-a$,  $M_0=1-a^2$, $M_1=4$, $M_2=4$, $l=\sqrt{1-a^2}$ and $2\sqrt{M_0M_2}=4\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

(i) When $a=0$, $|I|=l=1$, and  $M_1=2\sqrt{M_0M_2}=4$.

(ii) Given $\lambda\in (0,1)$, let $a=\frac{1-\lambda^2}{1+\lambda^2}\in (0,1)$. For this $a$, $|I|=\lambda l$ and $M_1=4>2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $f\geq0$. Then
$$
f(x+t)=f(x)+f'(x)t+f''(\xi)t^2/2\geq0.
$$
In particular, the points where the equation (for $t$) vanishes are
$$
t=\frac{-f'\pm\sqrt{(f')^2-4ff''}}{2f}.
$$
From here we have
$$
(f')^2\leq 4ff''\rightarrow f'\leq 2\sqrt{ff''}.
$$
Here the length of the interval plays no role. I think that this inequality is called Landau inequality. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you,But I have see this if the length of I is not less than $$2\sqrt{\dfrac{M_{0}}{M_{2}}}$$

Comment: I mean that the lenght of the interval plays a role due to the absolut value present in $M_0$ (otherwise any length gives you the same inequality). I'm still trying to figure out why...

Comment: Thank you,So I consider somedays,But I don't know this is why.