# Prove upper bound on derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ be twice differentiable function on interval $I$. Let $M_0=\sup_{x\in I}|f(x)|, M_1=\sup_{x\in I}|f'(x)|, M_2=\sup_{x\in I}|f''(x)|$. Show that

a) if $I=[-a, a]$, then
$$|f'(x)|\leqslant \frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{x^2+a^2}{2a}M_2$$
b) 1. if length of $I$ is not less than $2\sqrt{M_0/M_2}$, then $M_1\leqslant 2\sqrt{M_0M_2}$

2. if $I=\mathbb{R}$, then $M_1\leqslant \sqrt{2M_0M_2}$

c) Constants $2$ and $\sqrt{2}$ from b) cannot be improved

d) if $f$ is $p$ times differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $M_0$ and $M_p=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f^{(p)}(x)|$ are finite, then for $1\leqslant k\leqslant p$ $M_k=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f^{(k)}(x)|$ are finite and

$$M_k\leqslant2^{k(p-k)/2}M_0^{1-k/p}M_p^{k/p}$$

Solutions for b) and c) were given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206236/for-a-continuous-function-fx-how-the-supfx-and-supfx-determines-sup) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/502093/how-prove-this-mathematical-analysis-by-zorich-from-page-233).

d) was solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701512/prove-inequalty).

Now I am trying to solve a):

Using Taylor's expansion we have

$$f(a)=f(x)+f'(x)(a-x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_1)(a-x)^2\\
  f(-a)=f(x)+f'(x)(-a-x)+\frac{1}{2}f''(\xi_2)(-a-x)^2,$$
for some $\xi_1, \xi_2$. From this

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(a)-f(-a)}{2a}+\frac{1}{4a}\Bigl((x^2+a^2)(f''(\xi_1)-f''(\xi_2))-2ax(f''(\xi_1)+f''(\xi_2))\Bigr)$$

Using triangle inequality gives $|f'(x)|\leqslant \frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{x^2+a^2}{2a}M_2+|x|\cdot M_2$

How to eliminate that $|x|\cdot M_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Don't write $f'(x)$ as:

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(a)-f(-a)}{2a}+\frac{1}{4a}\Bigl((x^2+a^2)(f''(\xi_1)-f''(\xi_2))-2ax(f''(\xi_1)+f''(\xi_2))\Bigr)$$

but simply as:

$$f'(x)=\frac{f(a)-f(-a)}{2a}-\frac{1}{4a}f''(\xi_1)(a-x_0)^2+\frac{1}{4a}f''(\xi_2)(a+x_0)^2$$

and so it follows that:

$$|f'(x)|\leq \frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{M_2}{4a}(a-x_0)^2+\frac{M_2}{4a}(a+x_0)^2=\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{M_2}{2a}(a^2+x_0^2)$$

that is the claim.

Answer (score 0):

Taylor expansion about $x=x_0$ is given by
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(x-x_0)^2.$$
So,
$$f(a)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(a-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(a-x_0)^2,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$
and
$$f(-a)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(-a-x_0)+\frac{f''(x_0)}{2}(-a-x_0)^2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$
Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get
$$f(a)-f(-a)=2a~f'(x_0)+\frac{1}{2}(-4ax_0)f''(x_0)$$
$$\implies f'(x_0)=\frac{f(a)-f(-a)}{2a}+\frac{1}{2a}(2ax_0)f''(x_0).$$
Using triangle inequality, we have
$$|f'(x_0)|\leq\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{1}{2a}(2ax_0)M_2$$
$$\implies |f'(x_0)|\leq\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{1}{2a}(x_0^2+a^2)M_2~~~(\because (x_0-a)^2\geq 0).$$
Since $x_0$ was arbitrary, so
$$|f'(x)|\leq\frac{M_0}{a}+\frac{1}{2a}(x^2+a^2)M_2.$$

Comment: (1) and (2) are incorrect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem. You cannot write $f''(x_0)$ because the point lies between $x_0$ and $a$ or $-a$, but it is not $x_0$. Consider $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1, 1]$.